# Selected value not being set in dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox, html-select

I asked a similar question a couple of days ago and failed to mention that I have a second dropdown list on my page. The first list uses the Html.DropDownList, my second list uses the select statement.

I'm able to render the selected item on the repost to the first dropdown (SelectedItem) using the solution I was provided. But when I tried to apply the same technique to my second dropdown list (SortSelect) it fails misserably.

I don't understand why because they both are identified by id and I'm using the same ViewBag statement to send the data I want to display back to the view. What am I doing wrong with my second dropdown list that's causing the selected item to not render?

I apologize in advance for not being able to make the connection and solve this second iteration of essentially the same problem. I'm very new to .Net and still learning the basics.

**My View**

```
// This is the first dropdown list
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedItem", Model.ReverseMonthsLists(),
    new { @onchange = "CallChangeFunction(this.value)" })

// This is the second dropdown list 
<select id="SortSelect" onchange="CallChangeFunction(value)">
    <option value="default">Default</option>
    <option value="make">Make</option>
    <option value="model">Model</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option>
</select>

// This is my javascript
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function CallChangeFunction() {
            var dateItem = document.getElementById("SelectedItem").value;
            var sortItem = document.getElementById("SortSelect").value;
            window.location.href = "/dashboard/Report_Performance?dateItem=" + dateItem + "&sortItem=" + sortItem;
            }
    </script>
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Report_Performance(string dateItem, string sortItem)
{
    DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);
    if (dateItem != null && dateItem != "")
        newDate = DateTime.Parse(dateItem);
    var aVar = Models.Reporting.ListingStatsReportingViewModel.GetStats(userCurrentService.CompanyId.Value, Models.Reporting.DateTimePeriod.Monthly, newDate);

    if (sortItem == "make")
        aVar.CurrentListingStats = aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderBy(i => i.Make).ToList();
    else if (sortItem == "model")
        aVar.CurrentListingStats = aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderBy(i => i.Model).ToList();
    else if (sortItem == "year")
        aVar.CurrentListingStats = aVar.CurrentListingStats.OrderBy(i => i.Year).ToList();

    ViewBag.SelectedItem = dateItem;  //<- THIS ONE WORKS FINE
    ViewBag.SortSelect = sortItem;    //<- THIS IS NOT WORKING, IT'S IGNORED BY THE VIEW

    return this.View(aVar);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, your 2nd drop-down list is standard HTML so you've got to write a bit more code to 'set' the selected value. Ignoring the 1st list and JS method (they can stay as they are) you *could* try this:

*View*

```
@{
   string _sortItem = ViewBag.SortSelect == null ? "" : ViewBag.SortSelect;
}
...

<select id="SortSelect" onchange="CallChangeFunction(value)">
    <option value="default" @(_sortItem=="default" ? Html.Raw("selected") : Html.Raw(""))>Default</option>
    <option value="make" @(_sortItem=="make" ? Html.Raw("selected") : Html.Raw(""))>Make</option>
    <option value="model" @(_sortItem=="model" ? Html.Raw("selected") : Html.Raw(""))>Model</option>
    <option value="year" @(_sortItem=="year" ? Html.Raw("selected") : Html.Raw(""))>Year</option>
</select>
```

...

Honestly though, I'd make it more dynamic (like the other list) and supply the list values from the controller (via the ViewBag) then use `@Html.DropDownList(...` in the View for it as well.

Comment: Your suggestion was excellent! More importantly, your explaination of how things work was even more valuable. I implemented the solution but had to change "_sortItem" to "ViewBag.SortSelect". Otherwise, it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @csharpMind glad it helped. The top part of my answer with `_sortItem` actually verifies the valid existence of `ViewBag.SortSelect`. In the event that is null you could get an exception in the View by using the 'raw' ViewBag as a comparison.

Comment: That's good to know. I'll have to review my approach and make the appropriate adjustments, if any. Thanks again.